# Limit resources usage to a process on Linux without killing it

Tags: linux, memory-management, cpu-usage, cgroups

I need to run a Bach script on a Linux machine and need to limit the resources usage (RAM and CPU).

I am using `cgroups` but it does kill the process when exceeding the limits, but I dont want that, I just want the process to keep running with the maximum amout of memory and CPU I gave to it without it being killed.

Any solution for that? Or is it possibile to configure `cgroups` for the case?

Thank you

Comment: You generally can't force programs to make do with less memory than they want, but you could probably get them to start swapping instead of using more RAM

Comment: @thatotherguy thank you, could you please advise on how to do that?